# Punching a hole through TableView ViewForSectionHeader and accessing the view underneath

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, hittest, sectionheader

Alright boys and girls I asked this question before but i couldn't explain it well. And i feel i have a better grasp of the problem now

I have a tableview with 1 section header and 1 row per section. The header has a large image view and the cell has text and buttons. As you scroll through the table view the header with the image behaves normally, but the cell instead of scrolling underneath the header, it scrolls over the header view because i changes the headers layer zPosition. This is my intended effect. But when the row cell scrolls over the header, the buttons become unaccessible because the Section header is receiving the touch events. I cannot disable user Interaction in the section header because there is a button in the center of the header view.

The question is, how do i punch a hole through the header view and assign the hitTest to the tableview Cell beneath it.

Ive been working with hitTest and PointTest and it appears this is the right direction to go. but the problem is the views are all in different classes. Where do i place the hitTest and pointInside code? what should the objective of the code be? how do i convert the points?

I can pot code but I'm not sure how much it will help

Answer (score 3):

My advice is this: Stop.

Don't muck around with the table view's view hierarchy. Switching the z order of the table view's components, making things transparent to show other stuff underneath, etc. is all "bad mojo".

You are doing things that are very sensitive to internal, private implementation details of the table view, and are likely to break in future OS releases.

Comment: is there another way to create this effect? of one cell scrolling over another? or should i scrap the design? i really like the design

Comment: I would scrap the design.